# Discord Bot c# XP system

Tags: c#, discord

I am trying to make an xp system for a c# discord bot but my int wont save outside of the command for example to check balance or to purchase other items which would require me to check the value of there integer. Would I need to store this data on an sql data base or could would it be possible to just leave it in visual studio as an int. Thanks.

```
public class Buy : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{

    int coins = 24;

    int coins2buymeme = 23;


    [Command("buyrole")]
    public async Task Ishoping (IGuildUser user, IRole role)
    {

        string invite_code = "you have sucesfully purchased the " + role + " role for " + coins2buymeme + " coins !!!";
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(invite_code);
        await user.AddRoleAsync(role);
        Console.WriteLine("User bought" + role + "for" + coins2buymeme + "if you are not happy with this decision please change there roles on server manually");
        this.coins -= coins2buymeme;
        Console.WriteLine("your new balance is " + this.coins + " if you are not happy with this decision please change there roles on server manually");

        const int delay = 90000;

        string bought = "your new balance is " + this.coins + " if you are not happy with this decision please change there roles on server manually";
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(bought);
    }



    [Command("refund")]
    public async Task Ishopidang(IGuildUser user, IRole roles)
    {

        string invite_code = "you have sucesfully refunded the " + roles + " role for " + coins2buymeme + " coins !!!";
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(invite_code);
        await user.RemoveRoleAsync(roles);
        Console.WriteLine("User refunded" + roles + "for" + coins2buymeme + "if you are not happy with this decision please change there roles on server manually");
    }
    [Command("balance")]
    public async Task Ishopiddang(IGuildUser user)
    {
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("you have " + this.coins + " to spend use !shop to find out more");
        Console.WriteLine("User has " + this.coins + "if you are not happy with this decision please change there roles on server manually");
    }



}
```

}

Comment: What `int` are you referring to?

Comment: The coins int so that when a user buys a meme role there coin amount will go down and they will be able to see it in there balance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `coins2buymeme` is fine, better that you make it static and readonly.
(Unless you want the program to logically change the value halfway)

Now, your `coins`, do change whenever the user uses a `buyrole` command, but after the command is finished, the current instance of the `Buy` object is 'destroyed'.
And when you call a command again, a new fresh instance would be created.
Which means that the value of `coins` always start at 24 whenever a command is called.

You could change that to a global, static variable, but however that would result in all users having the same amount of coins.

I recommend storing it as a SQL database. Just make sure that you identify each user based on their `ID`.
The benefit of a SQL database rather than storing it as an object is when your bot shutdown, the value of `coins` stay for each user.

There is a youtube video tutorial on how to setup a SQL database on Visual Studio [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVV-LUcmCOE&t=2s). It also teaches how to use the .NET `SQLClient` with C#.

(Note: I recommend you learn more about object and class properties)

Answer (score 0):

Given the wording of the question, I assume you haven’t done much programming before. I apologise if I have assumed wrong.

When you run the bot, you are running an executable. Whenever an executable is run it can create variables (like ints) and store data in them. This will be done ‘in memory’ as the executable asks the the computer for some memory (RAM) it needs. However once the executable closes/quits, it gives the memory it took back to the computer, losing all that data with it. 
If you want your data to be kept when the bot closes, you will need to save it to the hard drive by saving it to files, databases, etc. You can choose however you want to save it that suits you. Most people would recommend databases as that can save your data and have it relate to other data making it easy to store and read complex data.

There is no general solution for what you want. If you want to save data, you will need to see what you need saved and then look into the different ways and see what you suits your needs.